# How to pass the row number as argument to SUMIF() function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have used the below code in my excel, getting run time error as object required.

```
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range
Dim rows As Integer
Set FoundCell = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(what:="Total", lookat:=xlWhole)
rows = FoundCell.row
rows = rows - 1
Range("C9").value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("A1:A" & rows), B9, Range("B1:B" & rows))
```

Thing is i knew the starting range of column, i need to pass the criteria and ending range of column as argument. can anyone help me to find the solution.???

Comment: You are using `SUMIFS`, which is a degree different from `SUMIF`. Also, `Dim rows As Integer` will fail if the `rows` is greater than 32767. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You only need `SUMIF`. Additionally, condition in `B9` is not properly qualified. Also, change `rows` to `Long`. See below:

```
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim rows As Long
Set FoundCell = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(what:="Total", lookat:=xlWhole)
rows = FoundCell.row
rows = rows - 1
Range("C9").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A" & rows), Range("B9").Value, Range("B1:B" & rows))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user3094542: If this was helpful to you, kindly mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark on the upper left side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, I doubt if you have passed correct parameters to the function `SumIfs`.

You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb239775(v=office.12).aspx for the syntax of the function.

And second, you are right in passing the range like this `Range("A1:A" & rows)`

Answer (score 0):

Either you can send formula as string or use Worksheetfunction.Sumifs

Syntax

`WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(<Sum Range>, <Criteria range>, <Criteria>)`

**Method 1** :

`Range("C9").Formula = "=SUMIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,B9)"`

**Method 2**:

`Range("C9").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("B1:B" & rows), Range("A1:A" & rows), Range("B9"))`